# Find limit of $(X_1...X_n)^{1/n}$ where $X_1,X_2,...$ are iid random variables uniformly distributed on interval $(1,2]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

> Find limit of $(X_1\cdots X_n)^\frac{1}{n}$ as $n$ goes to infinity, where $X_1,X_2,...$ are iid random variables uniformly distributed on interval $(1,2]$.

So first I need to show $ \lim_{n\to\infty} (X_1...X_n)^\frac{1}{n} $ exists almost surely, and then find the value of this almost sure limit.

So first of all, since $X_1,X_2,...$ are iid, this means that $Y_i=log(X_i)$ are iid random variable. Since $X_i$ are uniformly distribued on the interval $(1,2]$, this means $|X_i|\leq C$ and it also means $|Y_i|\leq C$. Now let $A_n=(X_1...X_n)^\frac{1}{n}$ and then $log(A_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i$. Now by using strong law of large number, when $n$ goes to infinity, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i$ almost surely converge to $E(Y_1)$.

$E(Y_1)=E(logX_1)=\int_1^2logX_1dx=log(4)-1$. Thus, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i$ almost surely converge to $log(4)-1$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Take logarithms and apply SLLN.

Comment: This might be easier finding the expected value of $\log X_1$ and then computing the exponential: $$e^{E(\log X_1)}$$

Comment: $$f_{Y_i}(y) = f_{X_i}(e^y) \cdot \left|\frac{d}{dy}(e^y)\right| = e^y$$
$$E(Y_1) = E(\log X_1) = \int_0^{\log 2} y \cdot e^y dy = y e^y \Big|_0^{\log 2} - \int_0^{\log 2} e^y dy = (\log 2) e^{\log 2} - (e^{\log 2} - e^0) = \log 2 - 1$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (X_1 \dotsm X_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = e^{\log 2 - 1} = \frac{2}{e}$$